# php mySQL, retrieve one row by number, store values as assoc.array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Pretty new to all this, so if I am going about my puzzle in a crazy way please tell me!

I have a table in a mySQL database with the columns title, hyperlink, imagelink

I want the php to select a row at random, then be able to save the title, hyperlink and imagelink as php variables. (so I can then output them into html)

so I could have for e.g

psuedoey code to get the idea

```
chosenNumber = randomNumber();

$chosenTitle = title[chosenNumber]
$chosenHyperlink = hyperlink[chosenNumber]
$chosenImagelink = imagelink[chosenNumber]

echo "<a href = $chosenTitle><img src= $chosenImagelink/> $chosenTitle </a>";
```

I think I need to use an assoc array like this here but I am very confused, because I looked through the various php mySQL fetch_assoc fetch_row etc and can't find which one to do what i need :(

What I have so far is

```
// database table name information
$number = "number";
$title = "title";
$hyperlink = "hyperlink";
$imagelink = "imagelink";

// sql to select all rows of adverts
$sql = "SELECT $number, $title, $hyperlink, $imagelink FROM $table";

//execute the sql
$data = mysql_query($sql, $link);

//count the number of rows in the table
$bannerCount = mysql_num_rows($data);

//generate a random number between 0 and the number of rows
$randomNumber = mt_rand(0, $bannerCount); //do I need to do bannerCount-1 or similar here?
$chosenNumber = $randomNumber;

//select data from a random row
```

First time post, be kind please, and thanks for any replies or explanations!

Comment: As a note - you can mark an answer as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the check mark underneath the voting score.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is a decent way to get a single row out of a smaller table.  The downside to using this method is that `RAND()` must be calculated for every row in the table, and then a sort must be performed on this non-indexed value to calculate the row you want.  As your table grows, `ORDER BY RAND()` becomes horribly inefficient.   The better way to handle this is to first get a count of the number of rows in the table, calculate a random row number to read, and use the `LIMIT [offest,] count` option on your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as rows FROM $table"
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  die('Error Checking Rows: '.mysql_error());
}
$rows = $row['rows'];

// now that we know how many rows we have, lets choose a random one:
$rownum = mt_rand(0, $rows-1);
$sql = "SELECT number, title, hyperlink, imagelink FROM $table LIMIT $rownum,1";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

// $row['number'] $row['title'] etc should be your "chosen" row
```

This first query asks the SQL Server how many rows are available, then `LIMIT`s the result set of the actual query to only return 1 row, starting at the random number row we picked.

Comment: Per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684989/one-complex-query-vs-multiple-simple-queries it seems that multiple queries would not be the solution, especially in PHP where you can only perform on MySQL query at one call. Is there a reason this is not true?

Comment: Faster than MySQL having to generate potentially thousands of random numbers and then index them - yes.

Comment: Okay, then that doesn't mean it's an end-all solution. Both are good. It would depend on the size of your database. Where do you draw the line? 1000 records? 100,000? etc?

Comment: Hence why I mentioned both methods..  `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is okay for smaller data sets.  I would think that anything over 1,000 or so records would save the SQL server a bit of overhead.  The `RAND()` query can't be cached by MySQL, but the `COUNT(*)` and `LIMIT offset, 1` queries can and will be optimized.  Creating a simple table and adding 5,000 rows to it made a 0.01sec query each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get records randomly, you can simply modify your sql query and each time you will get random ordering of records, just add `order by rand()` to your query and `limit` clause if you want to get just one random record:

```
$sql = "SELECT $number, $title, $hyperlink, $imagelink FROM $table
order by rand() limit 1";
```

Once you have done that, you need to use functions like `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_object` to get the rows actually:

```
$data = mysql_query($sql, $link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
  echo $row['title'] . '<br />';
  echo $row['hyperlink'] . '<br />';
  echo $row['imagelink'] . '<br />';
}
```

With:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($data)
```

You have `$row` array available at your disposal to echo values at any place of your page like:

```
  echo $row['title'];
  echo $row['hyperlink'];
  echo $row['imagelink'];
```

Comment: `ORDER BY rand()` can be quite expensive on larger tables

Comment: @gnarf -- Considering she was just grabbing every row, I think RAND would work.

Comment: @Kerry - It would work, yes.  However considering the OP was asking for a better way to do it, why suggest something that scales badly?  I also notice that you (and the two people who upvoted your comment) didn't upvote the answer, so it must not be that recommended :)

Comment: @gnarf: I have modified my answer by adding `limit` clause if the OP needed just one random row :)

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will only slightly reduce the performance penalty of using `ORDER BY RAND()` - MySQL will still need to generate a random number for every row, and then select the smallest value (without having an index to rely on)

Comment: Thanks everyone, plenty to think about, I will use the most upvoted answer as I understood it best, and I might need to think about scale issues, as I don't know how large the live table might end up.

Nice simple looking elegant solution, instead of my confused mess! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use the "limit" clause, it would be quite efficient:

```
SELECT number, title, hyperlink, imagelink FROM $table order by rand() limit 1
```

Why do you set up variables for the table name and field names?

Comment: I set up variables for the fieldnames and tablename because I am making this for someone else, who has not yet given me the details of the names of the columns in their database, so I have had to make an "example" one of my own to show the code working. I didn't want to have to and change all the code to make it work when they give me the live datam just the info at the top all in one place.