# Many SQL queries vs 1 complex query

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have a database with two tables that are similar to:

```
table1
------
Id : long, auto increment
Title : string(50)
ParentId : long

table2
------
Id : long, auto increment
FirstName : string(20)
LastName : string(30)
Zip : string(5)
```

`table2` has a one-to-many relationship with `table1` where many includes zero.

I also have the following query (that works correctly, so ignore typos an the like, it is an example):

```
SELECT t1.Id AS tid, t1.Title, t2.Id AS oid, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
    FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
    WHERE t2.Id IN
        (SELECT Id FROM table2
         WHERE Zip IN ('zip1', 'zip2', 'etc'))
    ORDER BY t2.Id DESC
```

The query finds all items in `table1` that belong to a person in `table2`, where the person is in one of the listed zip codes.

The problem I have now is: I want to show all the users (with their items *if* available) in the listed zip codes, not just the ones with items.

So, I am wondering, should I just do something simple with a lot more queries, like:

```
SELECT Id AS oid, FirstName, LastName FROM table2 WHERE Zip in ('zip1', 'zip2', 'etc')
foreach(result) {
    SELECT Id AS tid, Title FROM table2 WHERE ParentId = oid
}
```

Or should I come up with a more elaborate single SQL statement? And if so, can I get a little help? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684989/one-complex-query-vs-multiple-simple-queries

Comment: I would disagree, depending on the answer, as I am looking for specific advice on building my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with (and have upvoted) @Lee D and @Bueller. However, I generally advocate LEFT OUTER JOINS, because I find it easier to conceptualized what's going on with them, particularly when you are joining three or more tables. Consider it like so:

Start with what you know you want in the final result set:

```
FROM table2 t2
```

and then add in the "optional" data.

```
FROM table2 t2
 left outer join table1 t1
  on t1.ParentId = t2.Id
```

Whether or not matches are found, whatever gets selected from table2 will always appears.

Comment: I actually took this approach, because it worked for what I needed, but also, switching to a right join got me what I had in my post in a simpler way. Now I have the option to switch between the two. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, changing your INNER JOIN to a RIGHT JOIN should return all users regardless of whether they have an item or not, the item columns will just be null for those that don't.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Right Joins and Group By.  That will most likely get you the query you are after.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should prefer the "many queries" approach if (and only if)

- it gets you simpler code in total
- is fast enough (which you should find out by testing)

In this case, I suspect, both conditions may *not* apply.

Comment: +1 Agree, but I think I should err on the side of caution with regards to this query.

Answer (score 0):

You should come up with a more elaborate single SQL statement and then process the results with your favorite programming language.

Comment: Any suggestions on that elaborate SQL statement? My original one worked from `table1` where the new one will need to work from `table2`. But I am not sure how to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT t1.Id AS tid, t1.Title, t2.Id AS oid, t2.FirstName, t2.LastName
    FROM table t1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id AND Zip IN ('zip1', 'zip2', 'etc'))
    ORDER BY t2.Id DESC
```

You can have multiple conditions on your JOIN and RIGHT OUTER will give you all the rows in table2 even if they don't match in table1

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is called an `N + 1 query`. You have 1 initial query that returns N results, then 1 query for each of your N results. If N is small, the performance difference may not be noticeable - but there will be a larger and larger performance hit as N grows.